# Number of days difference in php

Tags: php, date, diff

So I'm trying to calculate the number of days offset one date is from another.  Currently I am using:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$dateToCompare = new DateTime("<filled from DB>");
$diff = $now->diff($dateToCompare);
echo $diff->format("%R%a");
```

What I'm finding is that this compares the dates and gives the offset relative to 24 hour periods, not calendar days.

For example, these dates have a day offset of 0 (where I would expect it to be 1):

> 2012-10-11 19:27:04 and
>   2012-10-12 06:50:00

Am I using this function correctly? I would expect this to be an offset of 1; however after lots of debugging, I have found that this is the source of the discrepancy I am actually seeing in the date offsets.

(The timezone is being set also as suggested by PHP)

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: what happens if you just use the date with out the time?

Comment: If you're getting the date from the database, why not just let the database calculate it for you instead?

Comment: I am not quite clear on what you are trying to achieve. You want to know how often the 00:00 boundary is crossed between two dates?

Comment: It is 0 because 24 hours have not passed between the times you're comparing... remove (set to 0) the time part if you want to compare in days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) using just month, day, and year to create your objects.

Maybe try the following untested code:

```
$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', date('Y-m-d')); // Note that if no timestamp is given, it uses the current time instead of 12am
$dateToCompare = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', "<filled from DB>"); //match format of db datetime
$diff = $now->diff($dateToCompare);
echo $diff->format("%R%a");
```

Comment: Got it - this makes sense.  Seems like this should be the default behavior even if you are comparing two dates which are including the time components ... 

If I was trying to compare Thursday at 9pm and Friday at 4pm I would expect this to be 1 day difference not a 0 day difference.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I found the first line caused an error - think it should say DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', date('Y-m-d')) - createFromFormat expects the second argument to be in the format defined in the first. I found that when you call the method like this, it still adds a time to the date object, based on the current time - like '2014-08-18 17:08:39'. It uses the same time for $dateToCompare, which prob means the diff should give us the correct result.

Comment: Good catch. That logic was indeed failing. It has been updated - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If youre looking for a simple way you can try this

```
$date1 = strtotime("2012-10-11 19:27:04");
$date2 = strtotime("2012-10-12 06:50:00");
$diff = ($date1-$date2);
echo date('j',$diff)." days";
```

The output is 31 days

You can replace the 'j' with the supported date format characters here
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Just use year, month, and date:

```
$now = strtotime(Date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2012-10-12 06:50:00")));
$pre = strtotime(Date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2012-10-11 19:27:04")));
var_dump(($now-$pre)/86400);
```

In my environment `DateTime` does not work.